# C# variable NumericUpDown

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I am trying to find a way to loop through my numeric up down, as in add a value to a numericupdown and then reloop to the next [NumericUpDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.aspx) giving it another value, in this manner:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 35; i++)
{
    br.BaseStream.Position = 0x6316 + i*4;
    numericUpDown[91 - i].Value = br.ReadInt16();
}
```

It keeps giving an error obviously because it's not valid. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: What's invalid about that? Assuming you actually have an array called `numericUpDown` of course..

Comment: an array ? no i don't think so, do i need one ?

Comment: Well, you're using array syntax here: `numericUpDown[91 - i].Value = ..`

Comment: ooooh alright thank you, wasn't aware i need an array to get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you want to get a reference to the actual NumericUpDown control based on the current "i" value.

One possible approach is to use Controls.Find() and pass it the name of the control like this:

```
Control[] matches;
for (int i = 0; i < 35; i++)
{
    br.BaseStream.Position = 0x6316 + i * 4;
    matches = this.Controls.Find("numericUpDown" + (91 - i).ToString(), true);
    if (matches.Length > 0 && matches[0] is NumericUpDown)
    {
        ((NumericUpDown)matches[0]).Value = br.ReadInt16();
    }
}
```